# How to get current user using devise in rails without using authenticate! on the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I'm using devise with rails 3 and i'm trying to create a page which can be viewed by everyone (even those not signed up) but has additional functionality for people who are registered.

The problem is that when I call current_user there is no user because I haven't used the authenticate! filter on my controller, because I want unregistered users to be able to view it.

How do I sign in a user if they are in the session otherwise leaving it without a user?

Comment: If this question is still active, Devise now always loads current_user for you regardless of using the authenticate_user! before filter or not.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `user_signed_in?` to add additional functionality in views.

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
... for logged in users only and current_user is not nil here....
<% else %>
... for anonymous users only and current_user is nil here....
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yeah except, user_signed_in? can be true and current_user can be nil.  What I want to do is make it load the current_user object if someone is logged in but not if they are not, and not require the user to be authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think to do this is to call it everytime you want to call current user, which probably isn't the best solution...
so it would be something like

```
if user_signed_in?
#code for current_user
else
#code for no current_user object
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note.  I wanted to find out if an admin user was logged in, and if so provide some helpful links & info on the public view page, so the admin could quickly jump to the admin section to edit the resource.

**However** if you generate your user as AdminUser(following the getting started instructions for ActiveAdmin) then the methods **user_signed_in?** and **current_user** are **admin_user_signed_in?** and **current_admin_user**.

So for example in a public view to show a post (views/posts/show.html.erb)  I can use (simplified for clarity)

```
<div id='show_post_<%= @post.id %>'>
    <h2><%= @post.title %></h2>
    <div class='post_author'>by: <%= @post.author%></div>
    <% if admin_user_signed_in? %>
    <div class='admin_links'>Put links to admin pages for: 
        <%= current_admin_user.email %>
    </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class='post_body'>
        <%= raw @post.content %>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect that the method names will be generated based on whatever you used when you set up your *users* in ActiveAdmin or Devise (if you named your *user* model Vip then the method would be **vip_signed_in?**).

Answer (score 0):

Not to nitpick, but it seems like both work in the same places, it is just that `current_user` isn't initialized if no user is signed in.

Here's a scrap of a line from a related idea, it's from a `before_filter` which prohibits users from editing items which don't belong to them

```
user_signed_in? && (@subscription.user_id == current_user.id || current_user.admin)
```

You have to wrap the whole bit with an `&&` on `user_signed_in?` though, or it will crash when no user is signed in.